# REACT.JS - map is not a function when I implement push to add an array to an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I display a list of items (arrays stored in an array) using the map function, now when I try to add an array to that array of arrays using the push function, I get this error: [image: Map is not a function error]

this is the declaration of the array (using hooks in react.js):

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({sideBarListItems: [["Hello", "YoYo"], ["MaHelloch", "MaYoYoCh"]]   });
```

and this is the map function and the push function:

```
              <CollapsibleSidebarCard title="SHIPPING">
                    {state.sideBarListItems.map((item, i) => {
                      return (
                        <SideBarListItem
                          key={i}
                          className="list-item"
                          icon={<i className="icon-rectangle" />}
                          title={item[0]}
                          leftTitle={item[1]}
                        />
                      );
                    })}

                    {console.log(state.sideBarListItems)}

                    <SideBarListItem
                      className="list-item"
                      icon={<i className="icon-rectangle" />}
                      title="Add Input"
                      leftTitleEnabled={true}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setState({
                          ...state,
                          sideBarListItems: state.sideBarListItems.push(
                            ["LETS", "GO"]
                            )
                          });
                          {console.log(state.sideBarListItems)}
                        }}
                        />

                    <CheckboxComponent label="Shipping Method Selection" />
                  </CollapsibleSidebarCard>
```

I was using a single dimensional array before this, and the concat function was working properly to add items to the array!
Please Help!

Comment: `state.sideBarListItems.push()` return's length not new array. Also, I don't know react hooks yet (maybe they provide immutability in this situation, but I doubt), but you're mutating the state directly by using push.

Comment: @Papi yeah, it returns new array's length, please how can I add an array to the array of arrays?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement my comment and Colin's answer. You want probably something like:

```
setState({
   ...state,
   sideBarListItems: [...state.sideBarListItems, ["LETS", "GO"]]
});
```

Also please avoid mutating the state directly (like using `array.prototype.push` on state property), `setState` should be used instead :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your `setState()` call.

`push()` will return the number of objects in the new array, not the new array itself.

So, you're trying to `map()` over a number, which won't work.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Oh yeah, I want to return the new array, how can I do that?